# Cannot add new object to a set, values come from a file

Tags: java, set, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to create a public instance method that takes no arguments and returns no values. It is required to get an input from a user to select a file, this part I have no issues with. The method needs to make use of the `BufferReader` and `Scanner` Objects. So that it can read the file selected. For each line that is read, a new object should be created and its instance variables set using the values found in the file.
That object that is created should then be added to a list. This is where I am having issues, it won't let me add the new object to the list. Below is my code:

```
public void readInEntrants()
{
    String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
    File aFile = new File(pathname);  
    Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
    Set<Entrant> entrantSet = new HashSet<>();

    try
    {
        String currentEntrantLine;
        Scanner lineScanner;
        bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile)));

        while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            currentEntrantLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentEntrantLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(" ");
            currentEntrantLine = lineScanner.next();
            entrantSet.add(new Entrant(currentEntrantLine)); // <----- Here is where I am having trouble. It won't let me add the new object to the class Entrant
        }
    }
    catch (Exception anException)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
    }
    finally
    { 
        try
        {
            bufferedScanner.close();
        }
        catch (Exception anException)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
        }
    }

    return entrantSet;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do. Could anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Sorry for got to add that it is a compilation issue, it will not compile properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "It won't let me"? Do you get an error or is it that the set does not contain what you expect?

Comment: "It won't let me add" did you ask it nicely? More seriously what error message if any do you get?

Comment: Have you overridden hashcode & equals methods for Entrant class ?

Comment: If it doesn't let you add an entry, it obviously should throw some exception(s). Please provide a stacktrace

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to add that it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE ,I bet you dont (otherwise it would mark compilation error immediatly with red -> **you use return in void method** ) and in this case you would see other errors.

(off: this would go to comment section however under 50reputation I am not allowed to do that. Stackoverflow should change this imo. )

Comment: I do use a IDE, and yes it won't compile. This is what I cannot figure out.

Comment: That is what I just wrote for you: void methods cant use return.      public void readInEntrants()    ---><----   return entrantSet;

Comment: But how am i to fix my code? The class must have a void type.

Comment: first of all remove the last line :
    return entrantSet;  OR  change the method to public Set<Entrant >readInEntrants()

Comment: I changed the type but i'm still receiving this error: constructor Entrant in class Entrant cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments, found; java.lang.String; Reason actual and formal arguments differ in length

Comment: Any help given is appreciated, the more i stare at my code the less i seem to know -_-

Comment: The constructor of your Entrant class doesnt take arguments , however you try to pass arguments here: new Entrant(currentEntrantLine)

Comment: All in all I would say ,you lack the very basics of java . In your shoes I would complete a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It seems the constructor of entrant class does not have any argument. Pass String as an argument type in the constructor to set the String field inside the Entrant class  .

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

You marked function `readInEntrants` as `public void` so you can't use return inside.
You could either remove `return entrantSet;` instruction or change function definition to `public Set<Entrant> readInEntrants`.

Concerning problem you have:

Basing on comment you left on beatrice answer I think you have only parameterless constructor for 'Entrant' class, while you try to create it passing string as parameter.
`new Entrant(currentEntrantLine)`

What you need to do is define Entrant class constructor that accept String as it's argument. For example:

```
public Entrant(String dataToParse)
{
// here you parse data from string to entrant fields
}
```

On the side:
You use `bufferedReader` to read entire file line at once and that's ok, but then you define `Scanner lineScanner` to iterate through line elements and then use it only once.
This way for file... let's say:

> One Two Three
>
> Four Five Six

Your while loop would work like this:

1. Store "One Two Three" inside `currentEntrantLine`.
2. Create scanner that'll work on "One Two Three", and set it to use space as delimiter.
3. Use .next to "Finds and returns the next complete token" (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())) and then store value inside `currentEntrantLine`. This way contents of `currentEntrantLine` is "One". Not entire line.

In next iteration you would have scanner working on "Four Five Six" and "Four" as `currentEntranceLine` content.